# Rabbitmq won't deliever message after service goes up again

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

In my system I use `spring-cloud-stream` and RabbitMQ for sending and receiving events. I got my RabbitMQ running, **service A** up and **service B** down. **Service A** sends an event to **service B**. Then I turn up my **service B** and now I expect Rabbit to deliever the event - but nothing happens. Is it correct behaviour? I'm new to RabbitMQ but I though that it should guarantee that all events will eventually finds its receivers. My application is simple, based on [example on github](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/stream-listener) with no extra configuration. What do I miss?

Comment: I don't know much about `spring-cloud-stream` but from RabbitMQ point of view - if your producer sends message `but there are no queues` where this message can be routed - the message will be discarded. I suggest you read a bit about RabbitMQ and its management API which allows you to check if there are any queues there and what happens with your message. RabbitMQ does not guarantee that message finds its receivers, its up to producers and consumers to correctly communicate through it.

Comment: Queues are anonymous, auto-delete unless you configure a consumer group. New consumers will only get new messages. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your consumers don't have a `group`, the queue is an anonymous, auto-delete queue. You need a group for persistence. See [consumer groups](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#consumer-groups).

Producers don't bind queues to the exchange, consumers do.

If you bind the producer first, before a new consumer group, messages will also be lost.

With the RabbitMQ binder, if you know the consumer groups ahead of time, you can set the `...producer.requiredGroups` property and the queue(s) will be bound.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_producer_properties).

> **requiredGroups**
>
> A comma-separated list of groups to which the producer must ensure message delivery even if they start after it has been created (e.g., by pre-creating durable queues in RabbitMQ).